# Can I fix this issue with my belt?

Tags: leather

I have had this black belt for pretty much a year now and it has started tearing at the hole that I am always using. Is this fixable or do I just need to buy a better quality belt? Also, if it isn't worth the money and time to fix it, what can I do with it, and how do I dispose of it properly?

In the past 3 years, I have changed two black belts because they all have the same issue. It becomes kind of annoying to go to the shop every time.

[image: Photo of tearing on the back side of a belt]

Answer (score 3):

I've only had that happen on quite cheap belts, made from some sort of processed leather product laminated onto a backing layer. It's not repairable; a repair would have to be cosmetic, flexible, and strong and nothing can do that.

I've never seen this with solid leather, but most of my belts are fabric or webbing. They last well too. So does the one I made from a bike tyre.

Answer (score 0):

The material looks multi-layered which suggests that at least the backing layer is not made of leather as tagged. If it is some kind of paperboard, then it is likely not designed for repeated bending and will fail with repeated use.

Is it possibly intended as a single season fashion item, instead of meant for extended use?

Fixing a thin fabric layer to the back across an extended length would likely make the belt serviceable, if not as pleasing aesthetically. Using black fabric or thin dyed leather would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a project it could be fixable for a while but if you just want a belt it's way more worth it to just buy a better quality one if possible.

If you happen to have materials at hand and want to try and fix it I'd start by punching 2-3 very small holes on either side of the rip to sew through. Try and avoid having them so big or so close to the holes you're going to use as a belt because this might start another tear.

Wrap the rip with a sturdy fabric possibly even a very dense batting as that will hold together well. If you use fabric, tuck the ends under. If you use batting, you don't have to worry about that. Wrap it on both sides and sew it through the holes.

Turn it over and sew the gap shut either using invisible stitches or not! It's on the back so as long as it holds together it'll be fine. Keep in mind this will still eventually come apart but it might hold you over until you can get a new or better one.

You don't have to but you could also use fabric paint on the entire patch to help it match the leather color and this would also seal the stitches in so it would last a bit longer. Good luck!

Comment: My fix was going to be to use the metal parts to make a new belt, from a bike tyre.  The reason I didn't do it is that in the end I made the buckle as well, from a sprocket and spoke.  In other words, I think if you're going to repair it, you should replace all the weak material